# publishProgress not called after canceling and re-create the object AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to make a seekbar that shows progress of music and when you drag the thumb item from seekbar, music progress change its actual value. All logic has been implemented in an asynctask, the problem is that when I cancel my asynctask from UIthread and execute it again the method **publishProgress() isn't executed** at all. The rest of methods (doinbackground, onpreexecute..) works fine everytime. Anyone knows why is this happening? Something about threads that i'm missing. 
thx!

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    mediaplayer.seekTo(actual);
                    update = new updateUI();
                    update.execute();
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    update.cancel(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                        int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                }
            });
```

Asynctask:

```
    private class updateUI extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {     
        while (mediaplayer.isPlaying() || isCancelled()) {
            //code
            publishProgress(actual);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
//code

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
//code
    }
}
```

Comment: You sould also share the relevant parts your AsyncTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have chosen a very non-traditional approach to this problem. Using things like this should be avoided at all cost:

```
    while (mediaplayer.isPlaying() || isCancelled()) {
        //code
        publishProgress(actual);
    }
```

People use `AsyncTask` for something that should be done in the background and without much interaction with "outside world".

If you want to make a media player, that should be controlled by the user, but work in the background, I'd recommend to use `Service` instead, bind it to your `Activity` and send data back and forth to control it. Services don't die when `Activity` is gone and you still have your music playing even if you quit the interface part. And when you restart your `Activity`, you may get back to controlling the `Service` again.

Comment: Thx lenik i'll try that, but now i'm curious about what was the problem